# how to pass in a value from child to parent class in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have Quiz class - child and welcome class -Parent

in quiz i have a disabling function

```
disableCheckLevel = () => {
  this.setState({
    levelDisable: false
  });
};

// rendering below
{currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      this.finishQuiz();
      this.pushtoDB2();
      this.disableCheckLevel(); 
    }}
  >
    Finish
  </Button>
)}
```

i want to send the value from the function as prop on click of the finish button to the welcome class so i can use that value in the welcome class for quizes. i dont know how to do this as it is going from child to parent.

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `onFinish` handler from parent to child as a prop:

```
// Parent

...
<Child onFinish={this.handleFinish} />
```

And in the child component, simply call that prop:

```
// Child

...
<Button onClick={() => this.props.onFinish(/* send param if needed */)}>
  Finish
</Button>
```

And finally, in the parent, you can handle it with a handler:

```
// Parent

...
handleFinish = (/* param if needed */) => {
  this.setState({ whatever: 0 });
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do pass a function to your Quiz. When you capture the click in Quiz, you call the function from the props to notify the Parent.

```js
class Parent extends Component {

  handleFinishedQuiz = (value) => {
    // Do something with value.
  }

  render() {
    return <Quiz onFinishQuiz={this.handleFinishedQuiz} />
  }

}

class Quiz extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
          onClick={() => {
            // All the things you need to do.
            this.props.onFinishQuiz('whatYouNeedToPassToParent');
          }}
        >
          Finish
        </Button>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: see the value i want is in welcome class i just want to trigger that when the finish button is clicked in the quiz class

Comment: You should probably share more code because I don't fully understand what you want to do.